# jQuery selector in instantiable portlets (duplicate IDs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, liferay-6.2

I've created a instantiable portlet, my problem is when I deployed in the same page two or more instances of this portlet, my jQuery functions don't work properly because my selectors only select the first element by ID or by class found in the document.

I was thinking to include in IDs the  in order to differentiate between the instances IDs.

My issue is that I can´t select the element with the , the console throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .tabOferta:eq(1)

The element i want to select is:

```
<li class="<portlet:namespace/>tabOferta" id="<portlet:namespace/>tabOferta">
```

I've tested the following instruccions:

```
$(".<portlet:namespace/>tabOferta");
document.getElementsByClassName('<portlet:namespace/>tabOferta');
document.getElementsById('<portlet:namespace/>tabOferta');
```

The problem is: How to select a particular element when there is more than one portlet with the same ID?

How can I resolve the `<porlet:namespace>` variable in the main.js?

Comment: IDs must be unique.  Must.  If your design results in duplicate IDs, then you simply must change the design so that there are no duplicate IDs.  If you need to select multiple elements with one selector, use a class.

Comment: I understand the uniqueness of a ID, but, if i change the jquery selector by class instead by Id, i have the same problem. When I deploy the same portlet twice in the same page, the class selector takes the first occurrence. How I can difference between one portlet js and the other ?

Answer (score 0):

you could always use css selectors to narrow down the elements. For example, "portlet:contains(tab0ferta)", but like Tony said you might want to change your design if your getting multiples of the same ID.